# Bind this to a callback function

Tags: javascript, bind

How can I bind this to a callback function, using call or apply?

```
    beforeModel: function(params){

        return this.get('session').authenticate().then(function(){
            this.findClient(params);
        }.bind(this)).catch(function(err){
          //retrieve new session
          return this.get('session').authorize().then(function(){
            this.findClient(params);
          }.call(this));
        });
    },
```

Throws an error at some point:

TypeError: this.get is not a function

This should referring to Ember Controller scope, why if I bind first with bind(this) and then call(this) throws an error?

Comment: How does the error look like? We need some more info to help you :)

Comment: `call(this)` or `apply(this)` will execute a function and returned value will be passed into `authorize().then`.  `then` should take callback function as param and then call `call(this)` or `apply(this)` on that it when it's time for it.  Given lack of context it's hard to give you a good answer though.

Comment: @morkro just updated

Answer (score 1):

You are better using `bind` for that.

```
function doSomething(){
    return authorize().then((function(){

       }).bind(this));
}
```

> The bind() function creates a new function (a bound function) with the same function body (internal call property in ECMAScript 5 terms) as the function it is being called on (the bound function's target function) with the this value bound to the first argument of bind(), which cannot be overridden.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Edit: You are still making the same mistake. The promise method `then` takes a function reference, so it can call it once it's settled. What you are doing is executing the function and passing to the `then` method the returned value of the function which in this case is another promise object.

Lets break it down:

```
beforeModel: function(params) {
  //Function to be passed down to your promise to find a Client.
  //Note that nothing gets passed down to the next step once the promise gets settled.
  var fClient = function() {
    this.findClient(params);
  };
  //We want this to be this (of beforeModel function).
  fClient = fClient.bind(this);

  //I have no idea what you are trying to do with the catch...
  var reAttachPromise = function() {
    return this.get('session').authorize().then(fClient);
  };
  //We want this to be this (of beforeModel function).
  reAttachPromise = reAttachPromise.bind(this);

  return this.get('session').authenticate().then(fClient).catch(reAttachPromise);
  //can be reduced to:
  // return reAttachPromise().catch(reAttachPromise);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    }.bind(this)).catch(function(err){
      //retrieve new session
      return this.get('session').authorize().then(function(){
        this.findClient(params);
      }.call(this));
    }.bind(this)); //!!
```

`!`-commented line was changed by me.
You bound the `success` function correctly, but not the `failure` function. Easy thing to miss!