# Call function from within a promise?

Tags: javascript

I need to call functionB from within a promise in functionA

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.functionA = this.functionA.bind(this);
    this.functionB = this.functionB.bind(this);
}


functionA(canvas) {
        let data = new FormData();
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
            data.append('data', blob);
            axios
                .post(`https://api.graph.cool/file/v1/${CONST.projectID}`, data, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    },
                })
                .then(function(res) {
                    console.log('res ', res); // res is as expected 
                    console.log('this ', this); // this is null 
                    this.functionB(); // Errors 
                });
        });
    }
```

However Im getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'functionB' of undefined
```

This is within a React component but I don't think thats important.

Comment: Please use the correct language tag...

Comment: Where and how have you defined `functionB`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bind this to a callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843547/bind-this-to-a-callback-function)

Comment: `this` inside of a `function() { ... }` will always mean the "invoker". Use `() => { ... }` notation instead to let `this` point to the `class`

Comment: @messerbill no, `this` inside a normal function that is invoked without an explicit context will be `window` or `undefined` depending on whether strict mode is in force or not.

Comment: because `window` will be the invoker at this time

Comment: @messerbill in no sense is `window` the "invoker" of that function.  That terminology simply isn't used.

Comment: @Alnitak https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp

Comment: @messerbill which not only does not use that terminology is widely discredited as a serious reference source.  Note that it _does_ refer to the _"owner object"_  but also (incorrectly) says "Invoking a function as a global function" when the same applies to any function in any scope that isn't called as `obj.method` or via `method.call` or `method.apply`

Comment: @Alnitak what is your point? the `vocabulary` of "invocation"? my god....name it the way u prefer

Comment: @messerbill precision of language is important.  If `functionA` calls `obj.functionA` then in normal parlance then `functionA` is the invoker of `functionB`, not `obj`.

Comment: @Alnitak i am by your side in the point of "precision of language". It IS important. I only wanted to demonstrate how `this` works in js. This is also the reason why i wrote this as a comment instead of an answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use arrow functions like this, regular functions have their own context ('this') while arrow functions take their parent's context:

```js
functionA(canvas) {
        let data = new FormData();
        canvas.toBlob(blob => {
            data.append('data', blob);
            axios
                .post(`https://api.graph.cool/file/v1/${CONST.projectID}`, data, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    },
                })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log('res ', res); // res is as expected 
                    console.log('this ', this); // this is not null 
                    this.functionB(); // no Error :)
                });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Review your code, `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"`

Comment: @dloeda cause its in the OPs codes context. everythings fine.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why he downvoted the best answer ??!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the function in your constructor ('this' is undefined)

this.functionB = this.functionB.bind(this);

Comment: ...and how exactly do we do that?

Comment: @chauhanamit i guess Jeremy knows about that....please update your answer and show what to do

Answer (score 0):

Inside .then() it's in a different scope. Assigning "this" to a variable ahead of time then using it inside the .then function will do the trick.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.functionA = this.functionA.bind(this);
    this.functionB = this.functionB.bind(this);
}


functionA(canvas) {
        let data = new FormData();
        let ctrl = this;
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
            data.append('data', blob);
            axios
                .post(`https://api.graph.cool/file/v1/${CONST.projectID}`, data, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    },
                })
                .then(function(res) {
                    console.log('res ', res); // res is as expected 
                    console.log('this ', this); // this is null (expected)
                    console.log('ctrl', ctrl); //this is the controller 
                    ctrl.functionB();
                });
        });
    }
```